Is it possible to have my DataSnap REST Project run on MacOS?
I want to make an API using DataSnap and it needs to run on MacOS, but when creating the project in the IDE. I can only select Windows and Linux. Why is this? Is it somehow possible to make it for MacOS?
I don't understand why I wouldn't be able to make it for MacOS.


No. The supported platforms are Windows and Linux for this project type. See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Mobile_Tutorial:Connecting_to_an_Enterprise_Database_from_a_Mobile_Client(iOS_and_Android)#Creating_a_Mobile_Application_that_Connects_to_the_DataSnap_Server for an alternative way to connect to a DataSnap server.
